# Android datepicker setmindate

Tags: android, datepicker

I have two datepickers in my activity. 
I want startdate of datePickerB dialog to be updated automatically based on date selected in datePickerA dialog.

I use **setMinDate** for datePickerB. setMinDate works fine for the very first time. But couldn't update or reset the mindate of datePickerB for consecutive updates in datePickerA. Kindly help.

Searched for all possible solutions but of no use. Kindly help

Comment: where are your tested codes?

Comment: post code for better explaination

Answer (score 0):

Below is my code. The code used in oncreate gets executed , but further setMinDate function called in HandleResponse ( this is the function that gets called once datepickerA is set )

//On OnCreate
        Calendar calendar = Calendar.getInstance();

```
    calendar.add(Calendar.DAY_OF_YEAR, 1);
    Date tomorrow = calendar.getTime();
    long t = tomorrow.getTime();

     fromDatePicker.getDatePicker().setMinDate(t);
```

//
         toDatePicker.getDatePicker().setMinDate(t);

```
public void HandleResponse(Response response)
{
    String sqlRes = "";


    try {

        String sResJson = response.body().string();

        JSONObject jReader = new JSONObject(sResJson);
        JSONObject jRes = jReader.getJSONObject("Result");
        sqlRes = jRes.getString("res");
        final int sqlMilkQty = jRes.getInt("qty");
        String enddate = jRes.getString("date");
        Date d = null;
        SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd");
        try {
            d = sdf.parse(enddate);

        } catch (ParseException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

            if (d != null && fromDate!= null) {

                long t = d.getTime();
                long t1 = fromDate.getTime();

                toDatePicker.getDatePicker().setMinDate(t1);
                toDatePicker.getDatePicker().setMaxDate(t);


            }

        Handler mainHandler = new Handler(Looper.getMainLooper());


        if (sqlRes.equals("PASS"))
        {
            mainHandler.post(new Runnable() {
                @Override
                public void run() {
                    milkQuantity = sqlMilkQty;
                    txtMilkQuantity.setText(String.valueOf(milkQuantity));

                }
            });

        }
        else {

        }


    } catch (IOException e) {
        DisplayError();
    }
    catch (JSONException e) {
        DisplayError();
    }
}
```

Comment: Any support for this ?